# How to fix a table causing "502: Bad Gateway" error in PHP

Tags: php, database, phpstorm, crud

I am creating a simple database that can do basic CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete) using php. I am able to complete the create, and able to see the results if I directly query the mySQL DB in the back end. But, I am having trouble getting the table to display on the webpage. It is instead displaying a "Bad Gateway" error if I attempt to display the database entries.

I tried removing the reference to the table, specifically

```
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>...
```

and the web page on front end works fine. Albeit can only see the data if I query the backend.

```
    <?php  include('php_code.php'); ?>
    ...
    ...
    ...

    <?php $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info"); ?>

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="test.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
    class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="php_code.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
    class="del_btn">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

    <!--in php_code.php--> 
     //to retrieve records
        $select_query = "SELECT * FROM info";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $select_query);
```

I should be able to see the table with data containing name, address and city. But I am getting a 502 error instead.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Mine is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
  include('php_code.php');
  $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `info` ");

  $return = <<<HTML
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
HTML;

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $return .= <<<HTML
      <tr>
        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['address']}</td>
        <td>{$row['city']}</td>
        <td><a href="test.php?edit={$row['id']}" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="php_code.php?del={$row['id']}" class="del_btn">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
HTML;
  }

  $return .= <<<HTML
      </tbody>
    </table>
HTML;

  echo $return;

?>
```

your php_code.php should really only have the database config...

Answer (score 0):

you are closing the php statements so you cannot retrieve the result of your query. Don't split php parts  and just echo html like this

```
 <?php
    echo " <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th colspan='2'>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead> ";
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { 

                echo "<tr>
                <td>$row['name']</td>
                <td>$row['address']</td>
                <td> $row['city']</td>
                <td>
                <a href='test.php?edit=$row['id']' 
                class='edit_btn' >Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href='php_code.php?del=$row['id']' 
    class='del_btn'>Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
       }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```